# How to setup auto layout constrains so that UILabel stays vertically centered inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uilabel

How should I setup auto layout constrains so that multiline label stays vertically centered inside scrollview until it's text content becomes too long to be shown at once? When the text length becomes too long text should be aligned at top with the scrollview so the user can see the beginning of text and scroll for more. This is how I tried to setup constrains

for scrollView:

- Equal Height to: Superview
- Align Trailing to: Safe Area, Equals = -8
- Align Leading to: Safe Area, Equals = 8
- Align Top to: Safe Area

for label:

- Leading Space to: Superview
- Equal Width to: Superview
- Align Center Y to: Superview

I also added following code to viewDidLoad()

```
scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

The problem is that but I still get some warnings and also text ends up "vertically centered" inside scrollview without possibility to really scroll to the beginning or the end of it, even when it can not fit whole inside. For scrollview I get warning that it **"has ambiguous scrollable content width"**, while for the label I get warning **"trailing constraint is missing, which may cause overlapping with other views"**

Comment: Just constrain the label to leading, top, trailing, bottom of scrollView.

Comment: Why not use a `UITextView`? You can set the `UITextView` to infer its height from its content and it will become scrollable once it reaches a particular size based on your constraints.

Comment: @creeperspeak constraining all label sides to scrollview doesn't work

Comment: @Rikh Content shouldn't be editable. I know you can disable editing of text view, but it seems there's even more job to make text inside textview centered vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about constraining the label height to the height of the `scrollView`'s superview? In that case the `label` will be always as big as the screen where it is presented, and since by default the text in a `UILabel` is centered vertically, you would get what you want. See the following Playgrounds example for reference:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class A: UIViewController {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let label = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(label)

        label.numberOfLines = 0

        label.text = "How should I setup auto layout constrains so that multiline label stays vertically centered inside scrollview until it's text content becomes too long to be shown at once?"

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),

            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor),

            label.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.view.heightAnchor),

            ])
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = A()
```

Comment: That solution works. By the way label height constrain works just fine if it's constrained to it's superview's (scrollview) height, there's no particular need to use scrollview's superview there. What I don't understand is why label's left and right anchors (leading and trailing) don't work if constrained to scrollview's left and right anchors, but instead need to constrain them to scrollview's superview.

Comment: @CodePoetics because by constraining them to the scrollView directly you will allow the scrollview to grow in X axis, not only in Y (basically you would make it horizontally scrollable too). by constraining it to scrollView's superview you are making sure it will fit the superview's width and won't grow over that value.

Comment: But isn't the scrollview already constrained itself. It's left and right anchor are constrained to it's superview. So it looks natural to me label can inherit those constrains from it's superview - scrollview

Comment: @CodePoetics look at the label top and bottom constrained to top and bottom of the scrollView. If it was the same, it would not be able to grow and then scroll.. The truth is I am not really able to explain why it works that way, but it works that way.. If you wanted horizontally scrollable scrollView, you would swap those constraints - you would constrain left and right to scrollView, and top and bottom to scrollView.superiew.. but again, how it is implemented under the hood I don't know

Comment: Anyway when I setup all these constrains in interface builder instead of writing code, Xcode still complained about ambiguous scrollable content width, although everything worked fine in runtime. In order to silent that warning I needed to add another view (content view) inside scrollview and completely constrain it to scrollview all 4 sides and also center it horizontally and vertically inside scrollview. Then I added label and constrained it's all 4 sides to this new content view. This time adding height constrain to label wasn't necessary. No warnings now, and everything works fine